# Minicart - Html text showing raw , required formatted text in magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

In mini cart i am trying to put a custom/formatted text but it reflecting raw html over there, required for magento 2.

Using Magento 2.2.4.

I expect html formatted text but the actual output raw text on minicart

[image: Detail Page]

[image: minicart]

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem">
        <plugin name="sr_DefaultItem"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;


class DefaultItem
{
    public function afterGetItemData(
        \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem $subject,
        $item
    ) {

        if (isset($item['options'])) {
            $options = $item['options'];
            foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
                $item['options'][$key]['value'] = html_entity_decode($option['value']);
            }
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

**Overwrite following template for change render type:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Now modify

```
<span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
```

to

```
<span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**[Update]**

Add following code in **di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
    <plugin name="st_config_provider"
            type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    private $json;

    /**
     * DefaultConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param Json $json
     */
    public function __construct(
        Json $json
    ) {
        $this->json = $json;
    }

    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        array $result
    ) {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
            if (isset($item['options'])) {
                $options = $this->json->unserialize($item['options']);
                foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
                    if (isset($option['full_view'])) {
                        $options[$key]['full_view'] = html_entity_decode($option['full_view']);
                    }
                }
                $item['options'] = $this->json->serialize($options);
                $result['totalsData']['items'][$index] = $item;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**OR**

Add following code in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository">
    <plugin name="checkout_item_sidebar"
            type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    private $json;

    /**
     * DefaultConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param Json $json
     */
    public function __construct(
        Json $json
    ) {
        $this->json = $json;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject,
        $quoteTotals
    ) {
        $quoteItems = $quoteTotals->getItems();
        $items = [];

        /**  @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item */
        foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $item) {
            if ($options = $item->getOptions()) {
                $options = $this->json->unserialize($options);
                foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
                    if (isset($option['full_view'])) {
                        $options[$key]['full_view'] = html_entity_decode($option['full_view']);
                    }
                }
                $item->setOptions($this->json->serialize($options));
            }
            $items[$index] = $item;
        }

        $quoteTotals->setItems($items);
        return $quoteTotals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it's working on minicart, but still not working checkout page.

Comment: Your question is about minicart, why you test in checkout page. For other page like checkout, cart page etc you need to do same things.

Comment: Please mention checkout page method for plugin.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Is it working for you? If yes, accept this answer that will help other.